# Increase and decrease number while pressing

Tags: javascript

I have two clickable spans that can increase and decrease number inside a input
by saving the opreation inside them using an id then loop on them and do the opreation using eval() , i want to increase the number and decrease it while pressing not only on click
(Long Press)

```
 <span id="--">-</span>
 <input class="num" type="number" max="50" value="0" min="1" disabled />
 <span id="++">+</span>
```

```
let num = document.querySelector(".num");
let controllers = document.querySelectorAll(".control span");

controllers.forEach((c) => {
  c.onclick = function (e) {
    let op = e.target.id;

    eval("num.value" + op);

  };
});
```

Comment: Do you want it to increase/decrease constantly while being held down?

Comment: Yes exactly I , want it to increase/decrease constantly while being held down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `mousedown` event instead of `click`, and set some interval that does your logic at some rate of time.

Also I'm not sure why you're using the `id` property and not some `data` property maybe, this isn't a safe usage of this property. Also you should use event listeners instead of directly adding the function on the property.

```html
 <span data-op="--">-</span>
 <input class="num" type="number" max="50" value="0" min="1" disabled />
 <span data-op="++">+</span>
```

```js
let num = document.querySelector(".num");
let controllers = document.querySelectorAll(".control span");

controllers.forEach((c) => {
  let interval
  c.addEventListener('mousedown',function (e) { // mouse down - start ticking
    let op = e.target.getAttribute('data-op'); // get data property
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      eval("num.value" + op);
    }, 100) // set interval tick time here
  });

  c.addEventListener('mouseup',function (e) { // mouse up - stop ticking
    clearInterval(interval)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
let score = 0;
let status = false;
const scoreEl = document.querySelector('#score');
const btnEl = document.querySelector('#btn');
let interval = null;

btnEl.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  status = true;
  update();
});

btnEl.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  status = false;
  update();
});

const update = () => {
  if (status) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      score++;
      scoreEl.innerHTML = score;
    }, 100);    
  } else {
    if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
  }
  
}
```

```
<div id="score">0</div>
<button id="btn">Increment</button>
```

Comment: No, but the idea is pretty close